# Existe alguma maneira de traduzir as mensagens de erro produzidas pelo PHP?

Tags: php, string, localização

Existe alguma maneira de traduzir as mensagens de erro no PHP?

Exemplo:

Inglês

> Use of undefined constant X

Português

> Uso de constante indefinida X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Tim S. já fez o trabalho de pesquisar isto e [postar no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11609263/221800). Ele acha que não compensa fazer mas pode editar um arquivo `.po` com as *strings* do PHP traduzidas. Ele indica até um [editor para isto](http://poedit.net/). Precisa do [Gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) e analisar o arquivo.

Ele apresenta uma outra forma que captura o erro e trata para apresentar o texto como você quiser:

```
set_error_handler('error_handler');

function error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext) {
    // Get the correct string for the error type
    switch($errno){
        case E_ERROR:
            $type = 'Error';
            break;
        case E_WARNING:
            $type = 'Warning';
            break;
        case E_PARSE:
            $type = 'Parse Error';
            break;
        case E_NOTICE:
            $type = 'Notice';
            break;
        case E_CORE_ERROR:
            $type = 'Core Error';
            break;
        case E_CORE_WARNING:
            $type = 'Core Warning';
            break;
        case E_COMPILE_ERROR:
            $type = 'Compile Error';
            break;
        case E_COMPILE_WARNING:
            $type = 'Compile Warning';
            break;
        case E_USER_ERROR:
            $type = 'User Error';
            break;
        case E_USER_WARNING:
            $type = 'User Warning';
            break;
        case E_USER_NOTICE:
            $type = 'User Notice';
            break;
        case E_STRICT:
            $type = 'Strict Notice';
            break;
        case E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR:
            $type = 'Recoverable Error';
            break;
        default:
            $type = 'Unknown error (' . $errno . ')';
            break;
    }

    // translate text
    $type = error_handler_translate($type);
    $str = error_handler_translate($errstr);
    $in = error_handler_translate('in');
    $line = error_handler_translate('on line');

    // echo the error in "default" PHP format
    echo '<br /><b>'. $type .':</b> ' . $str . ' '. $in .' <b>' . $errfile . '</b> '. $line .' <b>' . $errline . '</b><br />';

    // ignore the original PHP error handling
    return true;
}

function error_handler_translate($str) {
    // translate $str here

    return $str;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Engine/TranslatingError.php).

Não tenho experiência com isto e é a melhor resposta que consigo dar.

Comment: A pergunta era no intuito de algo como "instalar uma extensão e tudo certo!", mas pelo visto essa solulção é o que temos de melhor :\